# Numeric validation for textbox inside Gridview

Tags: javascript

I have textbox inside gridview. need to validate this textbox for numeric values.i tried using below code but its giveng me object required error.my code is as shown below.

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="tcexe" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0"  AutoPostBack="true">
<asp:tabpanel>
<asp:gridview>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" MaxLength="4" Text='<%# Eval("value") %>'
     OnKeyPress=" return AllowNumericOnly(this);"> javascirpt used is function 
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TenGrid>
</asp:tabpanel>

AllowNumericOnly(e) 
{ 
     var keycode; 
     if (window.event) 
          keycode = window.event.keyCode; 
     else if (event) 
          keycode = event.keyCode; 
     else if (e) 
          keycode = e.which; 
     else return true; 
     if ((keycode > 47 && keycode <= 57)) { return true; }
     else { return false; } return true;
}
```

i need to support this functionality in Mozilla and IE. can anyone help me

Comment: Don't mess around with key codes, just check the value. Can the user enter a decimal place? What about values that are dragged or pasted?

Comment: it should not allow decimals. only integers.

Comment: Then just validate the content with a regexp like `/^\d*$/.test(inputValue)` and give the user a hint if they've put in something other than digits.

Comment: thank u. this works but i wanted to implement in onkeypress event.i got the solution. we need to register the script in page load event

Comment: Cool. Your shift key seems to be broken. Your interface will be broken too since blocking keystrokes to prevent non-digit input won't stop pasting or drag/drop of incorrect values (i.e. it's an ineffective UI annoyance).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function isNumber(e) {
alert(e);
    //condition returns true when shift + tab or tab key is pressed
    if((e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 9) || (e.keyCode == 9)) {
            return true;
    }
    //for other conditions the shift key is disabled
    if(e.shiftKey) {
          return false;
    }

  var keynum = '';
  // fetching the key code for  IE
  if(window.event) {
      keynum = e.keyCode;
  }
  // fetching the key code for Netscape/Firefox/Opera
  else if(e.which) {
      keynum = e.which;
  }

  // 48-57 = 0-9, backspace = 8, tab = 9, 96 -105 = Numpad Digits
  // F1-F12 = 112 - 123, arrows = 37 - 40
  if ((keynum >= 48 && keynum <= 57)
          || keynum == 8
          || keynum == 9
          || (keynum >= 112 && keynum <= 123)
          || (keynum >= 37 && keynum <= 40)
          || (keynum >= 96 && keynum <= 105)
          || keynum == 46) {
                return true;
    }
    else {
                return false;
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
Test No. <input type="text" id="testId" onkeydown="return isNumber(event);"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtObtainMarks" runat="server" Width="50" MaxLength="2" OnKeyPress=" return AllowNumericOnly(this);"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        function AllowNumericOnly(e) {
            var keycode;
            if (window.event)
                keycode = window.event.keyCode;
            else if (event)
                keycode = event.keyCode;
            else if (e)
                keycode = e.which;
            else return true;
            if ((keycode > 47 && keycode <= 57)) { return true; }
            else { return false; } return true;
        } 
    </script>
```